# Can't display:none my mobile menu button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image: the menu button]I'm building a site for giggles http://briannabaldwinphotography.com/. My mobile menu button won't go away with `display:none` in safari on my iphone landscape mode, although it works in Chrome on my phone. I want the #menu-button to show when the device is under 500px and to disappear when it is above 500px. The menu button is added in through jquery with the id of `#menu-button`. If you use dev tool and look in the sources for css_tablet.css you'll see I have `#menu-button` set to `display:none`. Any advice much appreciated.

```
$("#menu").addClass("js").before('<div id="menu-button"><img src="third_logo.png" alt="menu"></div>');
$("#menu-button").click(function(){
    $("#menu").toggle();
});
$("li").click(function(){
    $("ul").hide();
});
```

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of which button you are talking about?

Comment: I can. If you make the screen smaller than 500px its rainbow colored in the top left just above the rainbow colored bar. You click it and a menu pops up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this CSS -

```
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {

    #menu-button {
        display: none;
    }
    #menu.js{
        display: block !important;  // You must have to use '!important' as javascript adding inline style on the menu (display block/none)
    }
}
```

Above CSS will solve the Button hiding issue and also the issue we talked on the last comments.

For better understanding of Media Queries for different devices. Look at this article - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: I had that same thing at the bottom of my screen_style.css sheet except it was (max-width: 499px). It doesn't seem to have worked

Comment: I want the menu button to show on any device below 500px, and to disappear above 500px. I apologize I think I did a terrible job explaining. It is working in chrome on my phone but not safari...

Comment: Using the javascript to take away the #menu-button instead of the css worked great thank you very much :)

Comment: I'm still curious why it wasn't working in Safari with CSS but I'll have to give up on it.

Comment: Well turns out its extremely glitchy, I'll probably just find a way to get the css to work.

Comment: I erased all of it from the hosting, but I can put it back if you want to see on your phone. It wouldn't act the same way whenever I reloaded the browser it was unpredictable. The main problem came from flipping the phone back and forth between portrait and landscape, and after I would click on a list item ('home' 'about' contact') then flip the phone the navigation would either be missing the menu button in portrait or the navigation in landscape.

Comment: if you can put it back would be easy to see what is causing the problem

Comment: it is script.js and I put all of the js inside of one document.ready

Comment: Okay. What it is doing is in portrait mode if I click on the menu button to turn it on then click it again to turn it off, then switch to landscape mode then the whole header is missing. Same thing if you do it starting in landscape mode and switch to portrait the menu button goes missing.

Comment: Its because you've the script inside document ready. Move it out of document ready

Comment: I did about 4 minutes ago. I put it at the very top of the js file.

Comment: updated the script on answer. But after you update in on your website, let me know. You might still have to apply some css, which i can find out after you update the script.

Comment: Okay. I updated the script it might take the hosting a minute

Comment: That's not quite right there are some side effects.

Comment: yeah.. remove the script. and all the above comments. You gonna have to do it using CSS. Put back the CSS you had at first. Its quite difficult as i cant make edits and see it's changes same time. But i promise, im going to give you solution! :D

Comment: I put it back to how it originally was with the original javascript, and the #menu-button{display: none;} in the tablet_css.css. I appreciate the help

Comment: I was on my windows PC. Now i've checked your site on my Mac. But i dont see the button when i resize Safari more than 500px. But i only see 1 issue. When safari's width is below 500px and you hide the menu by clicking on the button, the menu doesnt show if you resize more than 500px.

Comment: You are right. I didn't realize that my original code did that until like half an hour ago.

Comment: I have no idea how the menu button not disappearing above 500px got solved but it did haha

Comment: Updated the answer which will also solve the new issue!

Comment: I put in your code into my tablet_css.css although it doesn't seem to be working...

Comment: Nevermind its working now. Thanks a lot is there any way I can repay you? Bitcoins?

Comment: You need to use '!important' like the way i wrote it above. And not in max-width, you've to use it inside 'min-width'

Answer (score 0):

In your "css_tablet.css" all the css is defined within a media query which is applied only to screens with a min-width of 500px.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  #menu-button {
    display: none;
  }
  ... more css ...
}
```

In portrait view, an iPhone 5 is 320px wide, iPhone 6 is 375px and iPhone 6+ is 414px. So all of these phones dont apply the css from your "css_tablet.css" stylesheet.

So it isn't phone/tablet specific.

Comment: I apologize I just forgot to mention my problem is in landscape view on the iphone. Sorry! Portrait works just fine.

Comment: So there are two constants here. When the screen size is greater than or equal to 500px you; 1) DONT want to see the menu button and 2) WANT to see the menu. so it's safe to use this inside your tablet.css stylesheet.  #menu-button { display: none !important; }  #menu { display: block !important; }. This wont affect your mobile styles and will make sure that it displays the way you want on screens larger than 500px.

Comment: I don't believe that is working I'm trying it. I did try the #menu-button {display: none !important;} before I gave up and came here. It didn't work. In landscape mode the menu is already displaying the way I want I just can't get the 3 bar menu button to disappear.